# How to scrape images that does not load completely on page load using python/selenium/BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a e-commerce website, I can successfully scrape all data except the images. When I try to scrape the images the top 3 or 4 image urls I can get but the rest shows placeholders. Here's my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://pages.daraz.com.bd/'
offers = url + 'wow/gcp/daraz/megascenario/bd/ramadan_eidcampaign_april21/grocery_free_shipping'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Py\Hive-Ecommerce\static\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(offers)
output = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product2-in-a-row-item")))
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
driver.close()
for product in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product2-in-a-row-item"}):
    image = product.find("img", {"class": "rax-image"})
    title = product.find("span", {"class": "product-item-bottom-title"})
    price = product.find_all("div", {"class": "lzd-price"})
    discount = product.find_all("span", {"class": "text"})
    link = product.find("a", {"class": "lzd-item"})
    image = image['src']
    productName = title.text
    price = price[0].text if len(price) else 0
    discount = discount[0].text if len(discount) else 0
    link = link['href']
    print(image)
```

Is there any way I can scrape all the images properly?

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via Ajax. You can use this example how to load the images

Note: the script might need new values for the cookies. When you open Firefox Developer Tools->Network tab, you will see the requests there and all parameters/cookies:

```py
import json
import requests


api_url = "https://acs-m.daraz.com.bd//h5/mtop.lazada.kangaroo.core.service.route.drzaldlampservice/1.0/"

cookies = {
    "_m_h5_tk": "82c8b6ce7a958daa1f7ce6279854d666_1620564702086",
    "_m_h5_tk_enc": "1a493abf3c3bd09bc1254fdbd0974ecb",
}

params = {
    "jsv": "2.5.1",
    "appKey": "24936599",
    "t": "1620555452560",
    "sign": "df68466735d67d4fd3cd15e4d58dba7a",
    "api": "mtop.lazada.kangaroo.core.service.route.drzAldLampService",
    "v": "1.0",
    "type": "originaljson",
    "isSec": "1",
    "AntiCreep": "true",
    "timeout": "20000",
    "dataType": "json",
    "sessionOption": "AutoLoginOnly",
    "x-i18n-language": "en-BD",
    "x-i18n-regionID": "BD",
    "data": '{"pageNo":1,"pageSize":30,"pageId":80065583,"platform":"pc","appId":"1472729","bizId":"1000003","terminalType":0,"language":"en","currency":"pkr","regionId":"BD","cna":"","backupParams":"currency,regionId,terminalType,language,id","_pvuuid":"","curPageUrl":"https://pages.daraz.com.bd/wow/gcp/daraz/megascenario/bd/ramadan_eidcampaign_april21/grocery_free_shipping","isbackup":true}',
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, cookies=cookies).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data["data"]["resultValue"]["1472729"]["data"]:
    print(
        "{:<70} {:<6} {}".format(d["itemTitle"], d["itemPrice"], d["itemImg"])
    )
```

Prints:

```
Himalayan Pink Salt - 1 kg { হিমালয় পিংক সল্ট }                       1,150  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/81a56ce321dcb5aeae420f7974f12a80.jpg
Oolong Tea - 48G (Organic Chinese Tea)                                 380    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/233780dab25022001707d673697d50f5.jpg
SOGOL Saffron jafran { জাফরান } - 10g                                  2,900  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/624f8681b9eac9759012eee14803202d.jpg
Iranian Saffron jafran { জাফরান } - 5g                                 1,500  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/4ec398138ffcc4a69e9abdf80622f3ba.jpg
Chinese Herbal Drinks for immunity                                     380    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/4740514fc807143bf09405afb51be36c.jpg
Sona Pata Powder (সোনাপাতা গুড়া) 1000 Gram                             750    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/df4670876886daba1f7df0b4c388ba20.jpg
Green Cardamom Pods - 100g (এলাচি ) JAR                                490    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/43bd74cd21d448116c4b9de14ccbf58f.jpg
Himalayan Pink Salt - 1kg { হিমালয় পিংক সল্ট }                        1,150  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/81a56ce321dcb5aeae420f7974f12a80.jpg
Organic MCT Oil 500 ml (Brand- Agrilife, Thailand)                     1,800  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/4a4af95f047ff4f3710c47633ce70622.jpg
তেলাপোকা দমনের কোরিয়ান জ্যাপস জেল নতুন প্যাকেটে                        2,000  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/2fd4dd44a577a4756e11ca0f3a6060b5.jpg
Herbal health pack (ভেষজ হেলথ প্যাক) 250 Gram                          590    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/1be7fd5272ea05ea3fd7f9ee3db54f25.jpg
Gastric and ulcer herbal pack (গ্যাস্ট্রিক ও আলসার ভেষজ প্যাক) 250 Gram 590    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/5011ca734d95ac198197122457fc60de.jpg
Orjun Powder/ অর্জুন পাওডার-1000 Gram                                  890    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/56a1c4a87341702ed8e05bac7d2f778b.jpg
Organic Coconut Vinegar - Balsamic Style - 250ml                       1,600  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/eecc1ae4a58fd047ad0cf193c8704bf8.jpg
Dream Candy Lollipop 5pcs                                              400    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/c244366a6bc1412e6ccfe27f0d7aa728.jpg
Khalisa Flower Honey খলিশা ফুলের মধু 1 Kg                              1,500  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/196ee2abfc00c622485b89e45ed4120f.jpg
Whole Natural Dark Chia Seeds - 1 kg UK { সিয়া সীড }                   1,200  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/8390d0d916b9be4ecace753fdfa321a0.jpg
Manual Hand Juice Maker - Green                                        1,790  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/7feb58f07d05af10af44e1ae045dec38.jpg
Omor Corporation Manual Juice Maker                                    2,050  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/7d4599b4b28e20fc4cc78ac07b9da709.jpg
Pistachio Raw- 500gm                                                   1,320  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/75a76ab6c89df51a0264e25340b7fed3.png
Sunflower Seed - 500gm                                                 1,300  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/8d3f73f5cd037791bc38404833472a37.png
Whole Natural Dark Chia Seeds - 500g UK { সিয়া সীড }                   790    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/8390d0d916b9be4ecace753fdfa321a0.jpg
Black Seed Powder /কালোজিরা গুঁড়া- 1000 Gram                           690    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/2ee68eef315b6c6e18b2086f7a07926b.jpg
Rayner's Organic Raw & Unpasteurised Coconut Vinegar - 250ml           1,500  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/da7fd5b1a11109153ddbb72e8d2d7bd8.jpg
Bel Powder /বেল গুড়া -1000 Gram                                        690    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/5011ca734d95ac198197122457fc60de.jpg
Orjun Powder/ অর্জুন পাওডার-500 gram                                   490    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/56a1c4a87341702ed8e05bac7d2f778b.jpg
Himalayan Pink Salt - 500gm { হিমালয় পিংক সল্ট }                      700    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/81a56ce321dcb5aeae420f7974f12a80.jpg
Starbucks_Blonde Espresso Roast Coffee 200gm                           1,500  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/2e0145dfd770eb9d94a8429f39fcccf8.jpg
Sylhet Tea - Raw Tea ( রঙ / রং চা)                                     400    https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/9665c994f20f12170c60f6d21019d54b.jpg
Himalayan Pink Salt - 1kg { হিমালয় পিংক সল্ট }                        1,140  https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/81a56ce321dcb5aeae420f7974f12a80.jpg
```

Comment: hey this totally works. Just one question though. How do I understand which api is responsible for populating the page with products?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution with selenium.Data is loaded from external URL and need to take some time to load.

```
import requests
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
url = 'https://pages.daraz.com.bd/'
offers = url + 'wow/gcp/daraz/megascenario/bd/ramadan_eidcampaign_april21/grocery_free_shipping'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'*/*/geckodriver')
driver.get(offers)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product2-in-a-row-item")))
scrolls = 7
while True:
    scrolls -= 1
    print(scrolls)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(5)
    if scrolls < 0:
        break
html = driver.page_source
output = []
driver.close()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for product in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product2-in-a-row-item"}):
    image = product.find("img", {"class": "rax-image"})
    title = product.find("span", {"class": "product-item-bottom-title"})
    price = product.find_all("div", {"class": "lzd-price"})
    discount = product.find_all("span", {"class": "text"})

    links = product.select('img.rax-image[src]')[0]['src']
    print(links)
    if links.startswith(" https"):
        print('link : ', links)

    image = image['src']
    productName = title.text
    price = price[0].text if len(price) else 0
    discount = discount[0].text if len(discount) else 0
```

Comment: Hey this actually is a pretty good solution not changing too much on my code and I am gonna need this scroll down feature. But it still prints a few placeholder images.